# (React) dynamic component conditional setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a dynamic component that matches the data index with the URL parameter blogID I get with the with the router.

Here I have the router parameters and send the props to the component

```
<Route path='/blog/:blogId/:blogTitle' render={() => <BlogPost blogData={this.state.blogData} /> }  />
```

then on the component I set the initial state and I try to render the data that matches the index of the data, but I get an error of component repeatedly calling setstate and infinite loops.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            blogId:'',
            blogTitle:'',
            blogData:[]
        }            
    }
```

```
   render(){                  
        const { params:{ blogId, blogTitle } } = this.props.match;  

// so i map here to get the index and set the conditional to set the new state but I don't know where or how exactly        

        this.props.blogData.map((val, idx) => ( 
            idx == blogId ? 
                this.setState({blogData:val }) : null                               
        ))
        return (                          
          <div>              


           <BlogView title={this.state.blogData.title} />


          </div>
        )  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't setState inside render() function, the reason is that when you set state, compoennt needs to re-render to show user the updated data and then re-render again and again, instead do it in componentDidMount lifeCycle method so that it will run only once

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const { params:{ blogId, blogTitle } } = this.props.match;  
  this.props.blogData.map((val, idx) => ( 
    idx == blogId ? 
    this.setState({blogData:val }) : null                               
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting an infinite loop that is calling a setState in your render method, which causes a re-render, which causes a setState, which causes re-render...so on.

Try moving this part out of the render method.

`this.props.blogData.map((val, idx) => ( 
    idx == blogId ? this.setState({blogData:val }) : null ))`

Answer (score 0):

If you call `setState` in the render like this, you will cause infinite loops.

You don't need to `setState` once you find the `blog`, just use its `title` in `BlogView` after a `find`:

```
render() {                  
    const { params:{ blogId, blogTitle } } = this.props.match;        

    const blog = this.props.blogData.find((val, idx) => idx === blogId);
    return (                          
        <div>
            <BlogView title={blog.title} />
        </div>
        );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional block before calling the set state inside render. if the both values are same, don't call the set state.

```
   render(){                  
        const { params:{ blogId, blogTitle } } = this.props.match;  

// so i map here to get the index and set the conditional to set the new state but I don't know where or how exactly        

        this.props.blogData.map((val, idx) => ( 
            (idx == blogId && val != this.state.blogData) ? 
                this.setState({blogData:val }) : null                               
        ))
        return (                          
          <div>              


           <BlogView title={this.state.blogData.title} />


          </div>
        )  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I finally did it,

I set the state on the componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount(){                        
  const { params:{ blogId, blogTitle } } = this.props.match;           
  this.setState({blogId, blogTitle});
}
```

and the comparison on the render and it worked perfect

```
const blogger =  this.props.blogData.map((val, idx) => (             
            idx == this.state.blogId ?
                <BlogView 
                    title={val.title}
                    body={parse(val.body)}
                    img={val.thumb}
                />
                : null            
        ))
```